# PowerShell - Replace a character in a specific column in a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to replace `"-"` for `""` (nothing) in a many csv files, except for the `Name` column, which may contain `-` characters I need to keep.

Ex:

```
"Name","timestamp","CPU|Demand (%)","CPU|Demand (%) (Trend)","CPU|Demand (%) (30 days forecast)"
"ZY02-LAB-WinMachine","Mar 2, 2017 12:01:19 AM","-","38.07","-"
"ZY02-LAB-WinMachine","Mar 21, 2017 10:45:00 AM","40.55","-","-"
"ZY02-LAB-WinMachine","Apr 6, 2017 11:56:19 AM","-","-","38.69"
"ZY02-LAB-WinMachine","Apr 6, 2017 12:11:19 PM","-","-","38.7"
```

will become

```
"Name","timestamp","CPU|Demand (%)","CPU|Demand (%) (Trend)","CPU|Demand (%) (30 days forecast)"
"ZY02-LAB-WinMachine","Mar 2, 2017 12:01:19 AM","","38.07",""
"ZY02-LAB-WinMachine","Mar 21, 2017 10:45:00 AM","40.55","",""
"ZY02-LAB-WinMachine","Apr 6, 2017 11:56:19 AM","","","38.69"
"ZY02-LAB-WinMachine","Apr 6, 2017 12:11:19 PM","","","38.7"
```

The line I have in my script replaces ALL `-` in the csv ..  even the `Name` column  :-(

```
(Get-Content $ImportCPUFile) | % {$_ -replace "-"} | out-file -FilePath CSV-cleaned.csv -Fo -En ascii
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Get-Content $ImportCPUFile) |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"-"', '""' } |
    Out-File -FilePath CSV-cleaned.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
```

Comment: Génial  :-)

Working perfectly  ...   :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$Csv = Import-Csv -Path $ImportCPUFile;
$Headers = $Csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name;

ForEach ($Record in $Csv) {
    foreach ($Header in $Headers) {
        if ($Record.$Header -eq '-') {
            $Record.$Header = [String]::Empty;
        }
    }
}

$Csv | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation;
```

You may want to use `$Record.$Header.Trim() -eq '-'` for the comparison instead if you have leading or trailing spaces in some fields.

Answer (score 0):

Bacon Bits have very good code, but I think it can be little bit modified. What will happen if Name column will have value "-"?

```
$Csv = Import-Csv -Path $ImportCPUFile

$Headers = $Csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name;

ForEach ($Record in $Csv) {
    foreach ($Header in $Headers) {
        if ($Header -ne "Name") {
             $Record.$Header = $Record.$Header.Replace("-","")
        }
    }
}
$Headers = $Csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty


$Csv | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation;
```