# Keep numeric characters Copy non numeric characters to adjacent column CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

I am new to PowerShell, I've been working on small projects to learn how to use it.
Currently I have a folder with .csv files that look like so:

```
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"  
"Calss Section:","Section1",,,,,,,,,  
"Date","01/00/00",,,,,,,,,  
"ID Number:","1234567",,,,,,,,,  
"Name:","John D",,,,,,,,,  
"RunID","type","checktype","locname","type","instrument","limit1","limit2","read data","vIR","result"
"Values",,,,,,,,,,
"1","measurement1","PCB 1_1","A1 to B1","Res","<>","0.00","5.00m","4.25m","ohm","P"
```

I need to do some manipulation on the files and rather than do it one by one I would like to write a script to help me go thru every file and make the modifications need.

My goal is to split the non-numeric values from the "read data" column, so in my example would go from "4.25m"... to "4.25","m","ohm","P"
I really only want to do it to that specific column

I think the scripts in the post 
[PowerShell - Replace a character in a specific column in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188493/powershell-replace-a-character-in-a-specific-column-in-a-csv-file)
was my starting point

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: how do you know what row to work on? that ... disaster ... of a not-CSV file is so broken that i can't think of any programmatic way to find the property in question - only by counting. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: It's a pseudo-csv with experiment record. Meaning of each of 11 columns in a row will be determined either its first filed value, OR previous rows. Say for instance, if a line equals to ["Values",,,,,,,,,,], then previous line is headers, and the next line are CSV values.

Comment: i.e. in this example RunID = 1; type = measurement1; checktype = PCB 1_1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

below is my work-around

```
    $xl=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application  
    $xl.Visible = $True  
    $wb=$xl.workbooks.open("C:\Name2.csv")  
    $ws = $wb.Worksheets(1)  
    $range = $xl.Range("I1:J1").EntireColumn  
    $range.Insert(-4161)  
    $ws.Cells(28,9) = '=IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(H28,1)/1),H28,LEFT(H28,LEN(H28)-1))'  
    $ws.Cells(28,10) = '=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("m",H28)),"m",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("M",H28)),"M",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("k",H28)),"k",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("n",H28)),"n",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("u",H28)),"u","N/A")))))'  

$xl.ActiveSheet.Range("I28:I800").FillDown()
```